# xpath preceding-sibling correctly

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" border="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <tr>
     <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:2%">
       <input id="ucRightAdd_grdList_ctl04_chkSelect" type="checkbox"    name="ucRightAdd$grdList$ctl04$chkSelect">
     </td>
     <td width="65%" valign="top">
       <span class="BodyText"> Workflow View </span>
     </td>
```

In above html code I need to check the checkbox corresponding to text `Workflow View`. I used following code for that but its not working:

`Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., \"" +rightName+ "\")]../preceding-sibling::/td/input[@type='checkbox']")).click();`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the XPath

```
//span[contains(text(), "Workflow View")]/../preceding-sibling::td/input[@type="checkbox"]
```

---

Note that

- use `text()` in `contains(text(), "Workflow View")` to obtain the text inside the `span` tag.
- there should be a forward-slash after `[contains(text(), "Workflow View")]`
- there should not be a forward-slash between `preceding-sibling::` and `td`.

---

Alternatively, you might also consider using

```
//span[contains(text(), "Workflow View")]/preceding::input[@type="checkbox"]
```

which is a little simpler, but which also has a different meaning. The `preceding` axis traverses all tags before the current node excluding ancestors:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Workflow View")]/preceding::*')
[<Element tr at 0x7ff01f819f18>,
 <Element td at 0x7ff01f819e68>,
 <InputElement 7ff01f819f70 name='ucRightAdd$grdList$ctl04$chkSelect' type='checkbox'>]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with text(), but I dont know why not with [contains(., \"" +rightName+ "\")] where rightName is var. having rights value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one input per row, you could use following simple xpath:

```
//tr[normalize-space(.)='Workflow View']/td/input
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I think your problem is with the slash after the preceding-sibling axis. Per W3Schools you need a node test after the double colon: axisname::nodetest[predicate]

So instead of:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., \"" +rightName+ "\")]../preceding-sibling::/td/input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Do this:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., \"" +rightName+ "\")]../preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used the sibling concept.

First taken the parent tag and then traversing to the siblings

```
//input[@id='ucRightAdd_grdList_ctl04_chkSelect']//parent::td[@valign='top']//forward-sibling::td[@valing='top']//span
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).